# Particles Systems and Cloth Simulation

Tags: modeling, particles, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to do an animation of a rug that falls from a height but I discovered that particle systems can't become a real mesh, so the cloth simulation only acts on the mesh body emitter. Do you have any suggestions for solving this problem?

[image]

The scene is something like this, I move the rug up to the Z and then I let it fall for make this kind of exercise where the fall of the fabric make more realistic shape when hit the ground. The circule and the letters have both a particules systems that looks more realistic than made a carpet material for the mesh, but when I make the cloth simulation after this, looks like both mesh disapear and the cloth simulation hasnt any geometry for play with (only particules). I have been reading that I should put some bevel in the particules for get some geometry but the result of that doesnt look photorealistic like I want.
I really apreciate your fast answer and the posible solution for my problem but Im so bad with geometry know even knowing the improves that use them can make to my workflow, I should definitely work more in this topics and learn from cool tutorial and course online. Im trying to look for a solution that doenst need geo nodes in this moment. Im trying now the gypsy way of make the more realistic material of carpet in a normal mesh for later make the cloth simulation without problems like usually. **But I really want to try the simulation with real hair that looks much better**. I let this conver here for open a discussion and see the posible solutions.
Thanks a lot to all the people that make blender big and grow community cheers for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing more about your project, but Geometry Nodes can do pretty much anything particles can do, and if you use a Realize Instances node, it will provide a "real mesh surface" for the cloth simulation to interact with:

[image: Cloth]

In the example above, the Geometry Nodes object ("Balls") has Collision Physics attached to it in addition to the Geo Nodes modifier. The cloth plane simply has Cloth Physics added. Without applying the modifier, the cloth is still able to interact with the "balls".